# Exit from Crash debug mode in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, debugging

In Xcode (v 15.2), in order to analyze the production crashes in my iOS App, I go to
Window > Organizer > Reports > Crashes > Select a Crash.

Next I select a line and open the affected code in my project.

After analyzing the stack trace of the crash, how can I exit from the crash debug mode so that I can now debug the App normally?

Answer (score 0):

Simply select the crash item in the `Debug Navigator` then press `Delete` on the keyboard to remove it.

[image]